# Problems using literals and codeblocks with c# to interact with powershell 2.0

Tags: c#, pipe, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-cmdlet

If I try to run a `Powershell` Command through c# I get the following error:
"The term 'select' is not recognized as the name of a `cmdlet`, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

If the Command was executed directly with `Powershell(.exe)` all works fine!

The command I try to run looks like i.g:
"Get-Mailbox -Organization `'CoolOrganizationNameGoesHere'` | select `ServerName`"

It seems that there is a problem with the "Pipe" |, 
I have wasted hours on searching at major search engines with the wildest keyword combinations, 
but I've found nothing that works.

The last thing I have tried is setting the `PSLanguageMode` property of the published `IIS-Application` for `Powershell`, The result is still the same as written before.

Maybe there is `WinRM` wrong configured? Or my local `Powershell` configuration is corrupted?
Is there any well written documentation on C# (or any other .Net language) using `Powershell` with remote access
and using the Pipe | "command"?

Can anybody tell me what is wrong, that's like to find the needle in a haystack!

Thanks!

Comment: Please post sample code showing exactly how you're trying to invoke your Powershell script from C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trick could be in the way you create your command. If you are running script as a string, you should use:

```
Command myCommand = new Command(script, true);
```

But if you want to run it as a filename - you should use:

```
Command myCommand = new Command(script, false);
```

So:

```
Command myCommand = new Command("Get-Date", true);
Command myCommand = new Command("c:\test.ps1", false);
```

In case you need full method:

```
private static IEnumerable<PSObject> ExecutePowerShellScript(string script, bool isScript = false, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> parameters = null)
{
    RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
    runspace.Open();

    Command myCommand = new Command(script, isScript);
    if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value));
            }
        }
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

    pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
    var result = pipeline.Invoke();

    // Check for errors
     if (pipeline.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            //iterate over Error PipeLine until end
            while (!pipeline.Error.EndOfPipeline)
            {
                //read one PSObject off the pipeline
                var value = pipeline.Error.Read() as PSObject;
                if (value != null)
                {
                    //get the ErrorRecord
                    var r = value.BaseObject as ErrorRecord;
                    if (r != null)
                    {
                        //build whatever kind of message your want
                        builder.AppendLine(r.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name + " : " + r.Exception.Message);
                        builder.AppendLine(r.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage);
                        builder.AppendLine(string.Format("+ CategoryInfo: {0}", r.CategoryInfo));
                        builder.AppendLine(string.Format("+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: {0}", r.FullyQualifiedErrorId));
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new Exception(builder.ToString());
         }
    return result;
}
```